# Как узнать был ли отвечен исходящий вызов или нет?

Tags: android, broadcast-receiver, android-broadcastreceiver

Приветствую ! Как узнать был ли отвечен исходящий вызов или нет ( то есть взял ли человек трубку или нет, чтоб начать запись разговора ) ? Я могу вычислить это для входящих звонков, но никак не для исходящих.

Comment: Посмотрите здесь: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29490832/1263771

Comment: Ну это для Android >5.0